# Why the Rick's did not notice the bad Morty's brain waves?

Tags: rick-and-morty

According to Rick, the Rick's are so clever that they have their own brain waves. The bad Morty is clever too, so then why did the Rick's did not notice him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evil Morty is generally surrounded by other Morties. Even if he does generate Rick-like brainwaves, they would be masked by the other Morties around him.

Additionally there is no reason to think that brain wave scanning can be done automatically and Ricks are dismissive of Morties. They might have never thought to scan him.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that a Rick's brainwaves are so easy to identify because *they are so high*. Something that would not be out of the ordinary, in a room full of other Rick's.